# Our config version of 1 is no larger than the version on torvm-core20.xyz.com:27019, which is 1

Tags: mongodb

I was trying SSL enabled **MongoDB 3.7.9** replica sets. below is the code

I ran this command on **abc.xyz.com:27019**

```
> rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", configsvr: true, members: [{ _id : 0, host : "pqr.xyz.com:27019" }, { _id : 1, host : "abc.xyz.com:27019" }]});
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our config version of 1 is no larger than the version on pqr.xyz.com:27019, which is 1",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
        "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
        },
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1536753816, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0)
}
```

I did not find any hint on internet. Can someone guide me over this. I am not able to see the relica set created, Ideally it shouls have created.

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that you are trying to initialize a new replica set, but the node at `pqr.xyz.com:27019` is already a member of replica set configuration with the same `_id`. This error message is to avoid mismatching of RS configs by using the version value. See [the code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/a738647a7281a892f1b35fba8b4e1cdf47bccf56/src/mongo/db/repl/check_quorum_for_config_change.cpp#L216) for more details.